# Is there a web host that will allow http and NOT ENFORCE HTTPS?

Tags: reactjs, http, https, github-pages, web-hosting

I am looking for a web host for my frontend react project. I am 100% absolutely required to enforce http and NOT HTTPS, all the web hosts ive tried enforce https.

What do i need to also implement in my code to use http?

Thank you.

Comment: Need more info. Your site should run on http by default. Although be aware your users may receive browser warnings if your site is running on http rather than https. For example, see 'Secure Connection Not Available' section of firefox docs - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything in your code to use http.